# Failed To start Session Using PHP and Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session

I have problem with starting  session Using codeigniter framework trying to make a login but I can't login.

#### this is my controller code

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->input->post("login"))
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("username","UserName",'required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("password","password",'required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        if ($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $username=$this->input->post("username");
            $password=$this->input->post("password");
            $this->load->model("usersmodel");
            if($this->usersmodel->mainlogin($username,$password))
            {
                $session_data=array(
                    'username' => $username
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
                redirect(site_url("Users/dashboard"));


            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error With loGIN ');
                redirect(site_url("Users/login"));
            }

        }else{
            //error for validation
        }
    }

    $data['pagetitle']="Log in";
    $this->load->view("users/login",$data);
}
public function dashboard()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('username')==!'')
        {
            echo"welcom";

        }
        $this->load->model("usersmodel");
        $this->load->view("template/admin/dashboard");
    }
```

#### this is my model

```
public function mainlogin($username,$password)
{
    /*
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from("users");
    $this->db->where('username',$username);
    $this->db->where('password',$password);
    $sql=$this->db->get();
    return $sql->row();
    */
    $this->db->where('username',$username);
    $this->db->where('password',$password);
    $sql=$this->db->get('users');
    if($sql->num_rows() >0)
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

#### this is my view

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="container">

        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="final"><label class="text-success"><?php  echo validation_errors()?></label></div>
<form  method="post" action="<?php echo site_url("Users/add")?>"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Full Name :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name=" fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="please insert fullname" autocomplete="off" required="required">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">UserName :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="username" id="username" placeholder="please insert user name" autocomplete="off" required="required" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="password" id="password" placeholder="please insert yout password" autocomplete="new-password" required="required" >
        <i class=" showpass fa fa-eye fa-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Email :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="email" id="email" placeholder="please insert email" autocomplete="off" required="required" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">User Type :</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="groubid" >
            <option value="1">Administartor</option>
            <option value="0">User</option>
            <option value="2">Maker</option>
            <option value="3">cheker</option>

        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">Image :</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image">

    </div>

    <button type="submit"   name="adduser" value="adduser" class="btn btn-primary">add</button>
</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: please ensure that you have autoload the  session library eg $autoload['libraries'] = array('session');

Comment: Error With loGIN and i checked username and password

Comment: Shouldn't `if($this->session->userdata('username')==!'')` be `if($this->session->userdata('username') !== '')` — notice the `!` has been moved.

Comment: the same error  cant login

Comment: Are you sure this is right? `if($this->session->userdata('username')==!'')` "==!" ?

Comment: look in your `error_log` for headers already sent. this means you already started echoing stuff out so cant do any session headers anymore

Comment: I hope your not storing plain passwords in your database make sure when you create passwords you hash it with something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and then use a callback to verify password http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: ur password is stored with a some hash or bcrypt... or only plain text?

Answer (score -1):

Load session library in controller or in an autoload file:
`$this->load->library('session');`

Comment: i allredy laod it

Comment: means your are not getting any result from db which in turn return false as per your login function mainlogin. check database

Comment: i allerdy checked my database and  creat anew user name and password

Comment: $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from("users");
            $this->db->where('username',$username);
            $this->db->where('password',$password);
            $sql=$this->db->get();
            return $sql->row();                                                                                              uncomment this and run once, remove the code below this. to make sure run manual query to check you actually getting data from database.

Comment: select * from users where username='' and password ='' run this query in phpmyadmin after filling credentials and see if you are getting result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164815/discussion-between-ahmed-gaber-and-prasanna-puttaswamy).

Answer (score -1):

Replace this function in your model:

```
     function mainlogin($username,$password) {
            $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from("users");
                $this->db->where('username',$username);
                $this->db->where('password',$password);
                $sql=$this->db->get();

            if($sql->num_rows() == 1)
            {
                return $sql->result();
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: I don't think you have problem in starting a session because you are not getting $username and $password from session you are getting it from db.For testing session just autoload library session as prassana said then do the following $this->session->set_userdata('test'); after setting user data get it like this $this->session->userdata('test'); echo this in view if it shows test then session library is working good you have a problem in controller or model